# Different Screens for Different Users

Tags: c#, screen, projector

I'm writing an application and have been trying to find a way to have multiple screens for different users.

One user would see and operate the control screen and the other would see the output. Up until now I've been using cloned screens so both users can see the control screen.

The output would basically be hooked up to a projector.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use 2 different applications (one control, the other the display) and use a variety of messaging between (TcpClient, UdpClient, WCF, etc). Typically once an application gets here it has at least been attempted at. What have you tried?

Comment: both will be displayed from a single laptop, so that won't work for me.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Two users, one operating a control screen, the other viewing the output screen while everything happens on a single laptop is a bit confusing..

Comment: Use the Screens class to enumerate monitors and their working areas.

Comment: @AVIDeveloper The main application will control what is shown on another monitor. The monitor is connected to the laptop via a VGA cable, so we are using cloned display which shows the same information. I want a second form to show up on the monitor which just shows the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intead of cloning the screen, extend the desktop so that you can drag windows from your laptop screen over to the projector.

You then create two windows - the controller on the laptop and the display on the projector.

When you want to show the display window, you can do the following:

```
private void showDisplay()
{
    DisplayWindow dw = new DisplayWindow();
    // set dw properties if needed and make window visible

    // This is the part you are interested in
    int x = Screen.Bounds.X; // x-resolution (width) of the controller screen
    int y = 0; // top of the screen
    dw.Location = new Point(x, y); // Reposition the display window on the projector
}
```

This code will make the display window which you want to see in the projector visible only in the projector, while the controller will be on the laptop.